# Access class variables declared inside another class using frida

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, frida

I was trying to print an instance value which is declared using another `class` by using `Frida` how can I print the value of this instance, for example I have this code::

```
public final class myclass {
    public anotherClass A00 = null;
}
```

`anotherclass` contains the following code:

```
public final class anotherclass{
    public List A00 = null;
}
```

so my question is how can I print using frida the value like `myclass.A00` which obviously would output `null`.

so far I have tried this:

```
Java.perform(function () {
  try {
    let myclz = Java.use("myclass ")
    let anotherclassinstance = Java.use("anotherclass")

    var result = Java.cast(myclz, anotherclassinstance )

    console.log("A00 value ", result.value)

    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed!" + e)
  }
})
```

I have tried other several possibilities, Not able to get the result. the above `frida` script outputs an error `failed!Error: expected a pointer`

How can I print the value of instance `A00`?

Comment: First you can't simply cast `myclass´ to `anotherclass` unless the latter is a super class of myclass. Second, if you want the value of the field `A00` you have to access it: `classinstance._A00.value`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673164/150978

Comment: BTW: The code from your sample does only show regular field not class variables (the latter would be have a `static` in it's definition.

Comment: @Robert, using `classinstance._A00.value` with `classinstance=Java.use("myclass")` I am getting this `error` `failed!TypeError: cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: by `Java.use("...")` you only get a class reference, not a class instance, therefore your code fails. The field is only available in a class instance (because the field is not `static`). You have to select an existing class instance or create a new one. For the latter se the link in my first comment.

Comment: @Robert, I am still facing `failed!TypeError: cannot read property 'value' of undefined` with my `script` defined with new `instance` --- ```let classinstance = Java.use("myclass").$new()
    console.log(" myclass.A00 ", classinstance._A00.value)```

Comment: I would use 3 print statements, first print `classinstance` then `classinstance.A00` and then `classinstance._A00.value`. Then you will see if the creation of the object has worked at all. Also make sure the field name is correct (not sure where you got the code from in your question).

Comment: @Robert, the code is a `pseudocode` I made from `instagram` apk, and I posted [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531982/hook-instagram-apk-using-frida) about hooking instagram apk, if you could answer it.