# Hook instagram apk using Frida

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, deobfuscation, frida

I wanted to hook some functions from instagram apk using frida, decompiled the apk with
jadx/JEB, one of the functions I wanted to hook was in this:

```
    public static void A00(HGf arg8, I1Y arg9) {
        arg8.A0P();
        Boolean v0 = arg9.A0v;
        if(v0 != null) {
            arg8.A0l("about_your_account_bloks_entrypoint_enabled", v0.booleanValue());
        }
//some other code here
}
```

Tried to hook the function with this frida script:

```
  try {
    //

    let I1X = Java.use("X.I1X")
    console.log("this is instance: ", I1X)
    console.log(
      "these are the methods:: ",
      Java.use("X.I1X").class.getDeclaredMethods()
    )

    I1X.A00.overload().implemention = function (HGf, I1Y) {
      console.log("A0l is called")
      let ret = this.A0l(str, z)
      console.log("A0l ret value is " + ret)
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log("failed!" + e)
  }
})
```

this script outputs:

> this is instance:  <class: X.I1X>
>
> these are the methods::

> failed!TypeError: not a function

apparently the `A00` here is not a `function`, so back to `jadx` in the compiled code there is another class with the same name within same `package` but consisting of some other code, here it is:

```
/* renamed from: X.I1x  reason: case insensitive filesystem */
/* loaded from: classes7.dex */
public final class C39227I1x {
    public C39229I1z A00 = null;
}
```

apparently `Frida` is hooking this variable instance `A00` In my opinion that is why
it is returning not a function here.

So my question, how can I hook like this situation?

Edit:

the two classes are somewhat different in jadx.

Comment: Your class name is wrong: you try to hook `X.I1X` but the actual class name according to the Jadx comment is `X.I1x` (note the small `x` at the end).

Comment: @Robert, yeah that is true, but look at my code `this is instance: <class: X.I1X>` , that is actually the class I wanted to hook, the  one with the ending `X`.

Comment: additionally, when I used the `jadx` command line not the `jadx  GUI` with the commandline commands `jadx .\Instagram_227.0.0.0.97_apkcombo.com.apk --fs-case-sensitive --rename-flags none -d myout --no-res` I no longer see the classes and tried to find it in the subfolders it is not appeared then tried to grep some strings belonging to the class then none appeared.

Comment: You are on Windows, thus file-system is case insensitive -> Jadx renames the class. Only use jadx-gui with disabled deobfuscation.